# if $g$ is differentiable and $ f(-x) = \int_0^{x} g(\alpha) f(x- \alpha) d \alpha $ is $f(x)$ then is differentiable?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continous function and where $g$ is differentiable  and that

$$ f(-x) = \int_0^{x} g(\alpha) f(x- \alpha) d \alpha $$

for all $x$.

Can we assume that $f(x)$ is differentiable?

Comment: Can we assume that $f,$ or can we *deduce* that $f$?

Comment: Could you say something about the origin of this problem ? Just a homework ?

Comment: I am trying to find all continuous $f$ that satisfy that equation. I was trying to use integration by parts but $f$ may not be differentiable

Comment: See my "Edit 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer.

A first remark is that necessarily $f(0)=0$.

On the RHS, we recognize a **convolution** of so-called **causal functions** (because of bounds $0$ and $x$ in the integral), i.e, we can write the equation under the form :

$$f(-x)=(U.g) \star (U.f) \tag{1}$$

where $U$ is Heaviside function ($U(x)=1$ if $x \ge 0$ and $U(x)=0$ if $x<0$).

There is a result saying that the deivative of a convolution product is

$$(f \star g)' = \begin{cases}f' \star g\\f \star g'\end{cases},$$

choosing among the two RHS the formula that can be applied (for example the first one if $g$ is not differentiable).

In the case at hand (formula (1)), the LHS inherits from the differentiability of $g$, or more exactly of $U.g$, everywhere but in $0$.

Indeed, the fact that $g$ is multiplied by $U$ introduces a possible non-differentiability in $0$ or, even worst, a "jump" if $g(0) \neq 0$.

But I must have a closer look, for example by exhibiting a contradiction.

---

**Edit 1** : If we assume $f$ differentiable, one can differentiate the original relationship by using the general formula [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$\displaystyle {\frac {d}{dx}}\left(\int _{a(x)}^{b(x)}\varphi(x,t)\,dt\right)=\varphi{\big (}x,b(x){\big )}\cdot {\frac {d}{dx}}b(x)-\varphi{\big (}x,a(x){\big )}\cdot {\frac {d}{dx}}a(x)+\int _{a(x)}^{b(x)}{\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}\varphi(x,t)\,dt.$$
Taking into account the fact that $f(0)=0$, we obtain :

$$-f'(-x)=\int_0^x g(\alpha)f'(x-\alpha)d \alpha$$

If we set $x=0$ in this formula, we will get $f'(0)=0$.

Continuing in this way, if we assme that $f$ is infinitely differentiable in $0$, we will obtain as well, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$. ...

---

**Edit 2** : It's rather hard for me to believe that non-trivial functions exist fulfilling (1) ; maybe one of them could be a distribution.